# Angular CLI how to add id to style tag

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm creating a project with Angular CLI 1.3.0. At one point I need to get styles from a certain component.css file to put them into a new browser tab where a non angular page is shown.

I managed to do that by querying 'style' tags and copy the innerHTML.
Every component stylesheet seems to get its own 'style' tag.
The position in the queried array might change while further developing the application so I would really like to add an id to the style tag from the component.css. Is that possible?

PS: I know I could just copy all contents from style tags and I will do that if there is no other possibility to get the correct style.

Comment: have you tried with `:host-context`? https://angular.io/guide/component-styles

Comment: Can you elaborate please? I'm not sure how I could get the style information I need with that selector.

Comment: Do you have to read the styles from dom? Are u using jQuery?

Comment: I‘m not using jQuery and don‘t plan to use it. I don‘t have to read styles from DOM if there is another way to copy them into a new page (which is not part of the angular app).

Comment: But why are you trying to do that in the first place? Could you elaborate, it seems odd.

Comment: As explained in my question I need the styles to include them in another window document which is not part of my angular application.

Comment: Are you ok with a build time solution than runtime solution to extract the styles ? The reason I am asking is because if the component is not rendered you cannot get to the styles of that element.

Comment: Build time solution would be fine!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have jQuery avaiable and you are reading styles at run time (Angular application has rendered).

Inside each *.component.css* that you want to capture styles of, insert class:

```
.component-style-id-55 {
  margin: 0; // Important,  must have a single style rule so that this class gets through
}
```

This class will help us query style tag of a required component. `55` above is an example *numeric id*. This *numeric id* will help us sequence captured styles (if you want a different sequence from chronological DOM order).

Inside application, capture marked style tags (and optionally sequence them):

```
// Query all style tags which contain text ".component-style-id-"
// If found, retrieve numeric "component-style-id" and set it as attribute i.e. component-style-id=<assigned numeric id>
jQuery('style:contains(".component-style-id-")').each(function (index, element) {
    var componentStyleIdMatcher = element.innerHTML && element.innerHTML.match(/\.component-style-id-([0-9]+)/),
        componentId = componentStyleIdMatcher && +componentStyleIdMatcher[1];

    if (componentId) {
        jQuery(element).attr('component-style-id', componentId);
    }
});

// Now, elegantly query required style tags by assigned attribute and sort them ascending
var sortedComponentStyleElements$ = jQuery('style[component-style-id]').sort(function (element1, element2) {
    return +jQuery(element1).attr('component-style-id') - +jQuery(element2).attr('component-style-id');
});

// Retrieve style content from style tags
sortedComponentStyleElements$.each(function(index, element) {
    //console.log(element.innerHTML); // Prints style content of components in their numeric order of style ids

    // You might to remove angular encapsulation tags if you are using ViewEncapsulation = ViewEncapsulation.Emulated
    console.log(element.innerHTML.replace(/\[_ngcontent-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\]/g, ""));
});
```